# How to change option object AndAR Model Viewer

Tags: android, augmented-reality, andar

how to change object option from [AndAR Model Viewer](http://code.google.com/p/andar/source/browse/#svn/trunk/AndARModelViewer)

example in the picture below

[picture](http://i48.tinypic.com/2h50i6x.png)

Help me, please

Answer (score 0):

I think some parts of the code are missing on Google code but I am not sure.
However, I checked [this project on github](https://github.com/RaghavSood/ProAndroidAugmentedReality/blob/master/Pro%20Android%20AR%208/src/com/paar/ch8/ModelViewer.java) which was cloned from the project you referred.
The part that you're looking for is in ModelViewer.java.
It looks like the class loads all .obj files in the assets folder. (You can take a look at line 219)

```
if(modelFileName.endsWith(".obj")) {...
```

So the easiest way to change the option is to put your model in the assets folder and remove ones that you don't want.
You can start from there. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have removed some objects but after I replaced it with a new one by importing the object will not display in the rendering

Comment: If you're sure that your code is fine, it could be your model. There are currently some restrictions to the models: Every face must have normals specified. The object must be triangulated, this means exactly 3 vertices per face. Basic materials and textures are supported. http://code.google.com/p/andar/wiki/AndARModelViewerInstructions